# Powershell base64 vs regular base64

Tags: powershell, base64

I use powershell to convert string

```
$Text = 'ouser:v3$34@#85b&g%fD79a3nf'
$Bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($Text)
$EncodedText =[Convert]::ToBase64String($Bytes)
$EncodedText
```

However when using https://www.base64decode.org/, or some java libraries for base64 encoding I get a different, shorter version.

Sample string:

> This is a secret and should be hiden

powershell result:

> VABoAGkAcwAgAGkAcwAgAGEAIABzAGUAYwByAGUAdAAgAGEAbgBkACAAcwBoAG8AdQBsAGQAIABiAGUAIABoAGkAZABlAG4A

normal base64 result:

> VGhpcyBpcyBhIHNlY3JldCBhbmQgc2hvdWxkIGJlIGhpZGVu

While using the website I am able to decode both versions, however using my java code I am only able to decode the latter. Why is that? Is there more than one version of base64? Where those differences come from?

Comment: You're using Unicode encoding, meaning each character has two bytes, one is zero for ASCII.  Use UTF8 instead.

Comment: `[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode` is UTF-16, the latter is UTF-8. There's `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` that you can use.

Comment: Indeed, the encoding was causing this behavior. Unfortunately you cannot mark comments as answers.

Answer (score 37):

Adding the comment from @Raziel as an answer for better discoverability of this question.

`[System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode]` is UTF-16, the later is UTF-8. There's `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8` that you can use.